# Googletrans API Error 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Tags: python, googletrans

I use googletrans API every day,
but unfortunately, I got this error code today.

Is google updating the API?
Please help me with this problem.

```
~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\googletrans\client.py in translate(self, text, dest, src, **kwargs)
    180 
    181         origin = text
--> 182         data = self._translate(text, dest, src, kwargs)
    183 
    184         # this code will be updated when the format is changed.

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\googletrans\client.py in _translate(self, text, dest, src, override)
     76 
     77     def _translate(self, text, dest, src, override):
---> 78         token = self.token_acquirer.do(text)
     79         params = utils.build_params(query=text, src=src, dest=dest,
     80                                     token=token, override=override)

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\googletrans\gtoken.py in do(self, text)
    192 
    193     def do(self, text):
--> 194         self._update()
    195         tk = self.acquire(text)
    196         return tk

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\googletrans\gtoken.py in _update(self)
     60 
     61         # this will be the same as python code after stripping out a reserved word 'var'
---> 62         code = self.RE_TKK.search(r.text).group(1).replace('var ', '')
     63         # unescape special ascii characters such like a \x3d(=)
     64         code = code.encode().decode('unicode-escape')

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Comment: There is actually an [open issue](https://github.com/ssut/py-googletrans/issues/234) about it at [py-googletrans](https://github.com/ssut/py-googletrans).

Answer (score 3):

#### use certain version googletrans

pip install googletrans==3.1.0a0

works for me

Answer (score 0):

Try to switch to [google_trans_new](https://github.com/lushan88a/google_trans_new)

It has the same functionalities from google API and is working well.